# How to access $msg["CE"] inside function in php?

Tags: php, function

As i have two files i have declared variable $msg["CE"] in config.php file and i am trying to access that variable in function of login.php page ...

#### config.php

```
<?php
   $msg["CE"] = "connection_error";
?>
```

#### login.php

```
<?php
include_once "config.php";

function myf()
{
 return $msg["CE"];
}

echo myf();
?>
```

Please help me how to access that msg["CE"]

Comment: Use `global` to access

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP function use variable from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086773/php-function-use-variable-from-outside)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable is available in the file `login.php`. However, because you attempt to access the variable from within a function (of which you don't supply the variable as a parameter), you need to use the `global` keyword.

```
function myf() {
    global $msg; 
    return $msg["CE"];
}
```

You should take a look at the [documentation for variable scope for PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).