# Print php variable that is inside functions into HTML

Tags: php, html, printing

I have some functions that work together. But I need to print inside my `html` some variables used on these functions.

I know I Could:

- Echo the variable from within the function(function needs to echo it);
- echo the variable itself (but it needs to be global);
- Replicate those variables with globals (not a good thing to do);

Is it possible to print a variable that is NOT global, that is inside a function?

#### File.php

```
function myFunc()
{
   $var1
   //code...
}
```

#### HTML

```
<td> <?= echo $var1 ?></td>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP function use variable from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086773/php-function-use-variable-from-outside)

Comment: No, and for a(t least one) good reason. Either make the function return something to be used, or pass that var to that function in first place (by reference if you are really sure what you're doing), or, or, ... [Just don't make it global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why).

Comment: Obviously not, which values should it keep if it hasn’t even been allocated?

Comment: Did the provided solution help?

Answer (score 0):

The only way it is possible is by having it declared in global scope. Like:

**Method 1:** Passing by reference:

```
<?php
function myFunc(&$var1)
{
   $var1 = 32;
}
myFunc($var1);
?>

<td> <?= $var1 ?></td>
```

**Method 2:** Using a globally defined variable inside the function:

```
<?php

$var1 = 0;
function myFunc()
{
    global $var1;
   $var1 = 32;
}
myFunc($var1);
?>

<td> <?= $var1 ?></td>
```

**Method 3:** Returning the variable from the function:

```
<?php

function myFunc()
{
   $var1 = 32;
   return $var1;
}
$var1  = myFunc($var1);
?>

<td> <?= $var1 ?></td>
```

**Method 4:** You can set the variable as `enivironment` var:

```
<?php
function myFunc()
{
    $var1 = 32;
    putenv("var1=$var1");
}
myFunc();
?>

<td> <?= getenv('var1') ?></td>
```

**Method 5:** You can use the superglobal `$_SESSION`:

```
<?php
session_start();
function myFunc()
{
    $var1 = 32;
    $_SESSION['var1'] = $var1;
}
myFunc();
?>

<td> <?= $_SESSION['var1'] ?></td>
```