# Undefined Index Error Laravel 5.4 Where Clause

Tags: laravel

I developed following code,

```
public function getInCalls($sip_id){  

      $resultsTotalInCalls =  DB::table('xxxx')
    ->whereDate('created', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->where(function ($query) {

    $query->where([
    ['event', '=', 'ENTERQUEUE'],
    ['agent', '=', $sip_id]

]);
    })

    ->get();  

     $numberofInCalls =  count($resultsTotalInCalls);   

     return $numberofInCalls;

}
```

But I got undefined index $sip_id in  `['agent', '=', $sip_id]` line. How to pass $sip_id in to function? I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closures needs importing variables from outside.

```
->where(function ($query) use ($sip_id) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public function getInCalls($sip_id){  

          $resultsTotalInCalls =  DB::table('xxxx')
        ->whereDate('created', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
        ->where(function ($query) use($sip_id) {

        $query->where([
        ['event', '=', 'ENTERQUEUE'],
        ['agent', '=', $sip_id]

    ]);
        })

        ->get();  

         $numberofInCalls =  count($resultsTotalInCalls);   

         return $numberofInCalls;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you'd rather use closures then you can import variable to the current scope (the `use` keyword):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11086796/3520693

```
public function getInCalls($sip_id){

    $resultsTotalInCalls =  DB::table('xxxx')
        ->whereDate('created', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
        ->where(function ($query) use ($sip_id) {

            $query->where([
                ['event', '=', 'ENTERQUEUE'],
                ['agent', '=', $sip_id]

            ]);
        })

        ->get();

    $numberofInCalls =  count($resultsTotalInCalls);

    return $numberofInCalls;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getInCalls($sip_id){
    $resultsTotalInCalls =  DB::table('abc')
        ->whereDate('created', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
        ->where(function ($query) use ($sip_id) {
            $query->where([ ['event', '=', 'ENTERQUEUE'], ['agent', '=', $sip_id]  ]); 
        })
        ->get();  
    $numberofInCalls =  count($resultsTotalInCalls);
    return $numberofInCalls;  
}
```