# Undefined variable with include or require

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I'm trying to include a variable from a different file into my main php file but I keep getting `Undefined variable`.

accounts.php

```
# GUEST CREDENTIALS
$host = 'localhost';
$guestAccount = 'oncofinder';
$guestPassword = 'xxxxxx';
$database = 'oncofinder';

#LOGGER CREDENTIALS
$loggerAccount = 'logger';
$loggerPassword = 'xxxxx';
```

connections.php

```
function guestConnection() {



    try {
        require 'accounts.php';


        $conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $guestAccount, $guestPassword);
    }   catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error : " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }

    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}
```

I tried to put my require in and out of my function but nothing works. I really thought this was straightfoward but I can't find an obvious solution.

Is there any thing I'm doing wrong? Isn't this the procedure?

Regards

Comment: does `accounts.php` live on the same tree-level as `connections.php`?

Comment: Yes, it does @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs

Comment: You may consider reading this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11086796/1860540

Comment: Can you give the full error as you see it on your screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have variables defined in global scope but you try to use it in local scope.

To confirm naming scope issue try to:

```
require 'accounts.php';
function guestConnection() {
    global $host, $database, $guestAccount, $guestPassword;
    try {
       $conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $guestAccount, $guestPassword);
    ...
```

This should work if your `guestConnection()` is in global scope not under any namespace or class.

or do move require out of `try` to get errors if any (file does not exist?):

```
function guestConnection() {
    require('accounts.php');
    try {
       $conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $guestAccount, $guestPassword);
    ...
```

Comment: this is a good point - are there any security risk implications with using global keyword with db vars?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on my CentOS server. Try using the full absolute path (server conf might not be configured to allow calling of same-level files this way):

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/path/to/accounts.php';
```

Note:

you can use `require` and it should still work. I just think `require_once` is safer (in terms of not accidentally duping code).