# Which PHP function returns a smaller version of my associative array containing only keys present as values in a second array?

Tags: php, function

The PHP function that I'm looking for is similar to `array_intersect_key()`.

If I have an associative array called `$populations[]`, and a numerical array called `$countries[]`, which function will return a modified version of `$populations[]` with only keys present as values in `$countries`?

Here's a pair of arrays that I may want such a function for:

```
$populations = [
    'Sweden' => 6476727,
    'Denmark' => 3722898,
    'Finland' => 3417691,
    'Norway' => 3511912,
    'Iceland' => 247524
];

$countries = [
    'Sweden',
    'Denmark',
    'Norway'
];
```

Which function will take those two arrays as input, and output the following array?

```
['Sweden']=> 6476727
['Denmark']=> 3722898
['Norway']=> 3511912
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a single function that does it. But you can flip `$countries` into an associative array and then use `array_intersect_key()`.

```
$result = array_intersect_key($populations, array_flip($countries));
```

Answer (score 1):

With array_combine and array_map:

```
$result = array_combine(
  $countries,
  array_map(fn($country) => $populations[$country], $countries)
);
```

With array_reduce:

```
$result = array_reduce(
  $countries,
  function ($carry, $country) use ($populations) {
    $carry[$country] = $populations[$country];
    return $carry;
  },
  []
);
```

Or with array_reduce and an arrow function (the array_merge can become expensive if the resulting array becomes big):

```
$result = array_reduce(
  $countries,
  fn($carry, $country) => array_merge($carry, [ $country => $populations[$country] ]),
  []
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter), you pass a simple custom callback closure that returns `true` if the item is to be included in the resulting array, in this case :`in_array($key, $countries)`.

```php
$populations = [
    'Sweden' => 6476727,
    'Denmark' => 3722898,
    'Finland' => 3417691,
    'Norway' => 3511912,
    'Iceland' => 247524
];

$countries = [
    'Sweden',
    'Denmark',
    'Norway'
];

$filtered = array_filter($populations, function($key) use ($countries) {
    return in_array($key, $countries);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

var_export($filtered);
/*
array (
  'Sweden' => 6476727,
  'Denmark' => 3722898,
  'Norway' => 3511912,
)
*/
```

Also, see [PHP function use variable from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086773/php-function-use-variable-from-outside)

### Note:

This will be less performant than [Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76493528/6127393), but will be easier to understand when you revisit the code weeks, months, or years later.