# Best way to receive variables from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a custom Wordpress table with the following contents:

```
account_info
id   | account_id | wp_title | wp_url
1    | 12345      | website  | website.com
```

What is the best (or fastest) way to get the results?

**Option 1:**

```
global $wpdb;   

$sql = "SELECT id, wp_title. wp_name FROM account_info";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

if(!empty($results)) { 
    foreach($results as $r) {   
         $id = $r->id;
         $wp_title = $r->wp_title;
         $wp_name = $r->wp_name;

    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
$id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT id FROM account_info");
$wp_title = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT wp_title FROM account_info");
$wp_name = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT wp_name FROM account_info");
```

Comment: Obiously Option1..at a glance you are getting all the results.

Comment: Always minimize the number of database searches where possible.

Comment: Option 2 is better when you need to get only ONE variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are talking about "best" and "fastest" - these aren't the only things you need to take into consideration. *Readibility* is also key for future developers looking at your code.

Option one clearly shows that, if the result set isn't empty, you loop around them and set some variables. Option two is *framework specific*, and this isn't always the best approach.

So *before* micro-optimising, make sure *readability* is at it's utmost - never sacrifice one for the other.

Speed-wise, just make sure you're indexing your database properly. You're using the fastest loops available to PHP. Also, option two is making multiple database queries. Always try and combine multiple queries into one - you don't need to make a load of extra calls to the db that you don't actually need.

You want to avoid using the `global` keyword. It's bad practice and makes your code untestable. Get access to the `$wpdb` variable another way, either by passing it into a function or including a file elsewhere. See [why global variables are bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715897/why-is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-global-reference-inside-functions) and search a little on google.

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on your objective, query language and the metta data design around indexing etc.

In you example above collecting your results as an object above and iterating through would be the best option, if more than one option is available.

If only ever expecting a singular result to be safe ad LIMIT 1 in your query and access your object properties accordingly

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I recommend the option 1, but even better I recommend using  prepared statements, suggested by many authors. It avoids abuse of the protocol and mimimize data transfers.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, wp_title. wp_name FROM account_info");
if ($stmt->execute(array())) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
     $id = $row['id'];
     $wp_title = $row['wp_title'];
     $wp_name = $row['wp_name']; 
  }
}
```