# copy dynamic value to array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Can we copy all the dynamic values to array for eg:
I have a function like this

```
<?php

 $list_a = array(); //defining an array
 $list_b = array();
 $list_c = array();
addText($a,$b,$c)
{
 $list_a[] = $a;
 $list_b[] = $b;
 $list_c[] = $c;
}
```

I will pass different values to addText() function after that I have to access those inserted value using **foreach** from ***another function***.

How can we do that .

Comment: Besides that you are missing a dollar sign, you can just do: `$list_a[] = $a;`. I don't really see, where your problem/question is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define your php variable as global.

```
Eg. global $list_a,$list_b,$list_c;
```

When you are using that variable in any function then first declare above variables in that function.
Eg:

```
addText($a,$b,$c)
{
global $list_a,$list_b,$list_c;
 $list_a[] = $a;
 $list_b[] = $b;
 $list_c[] = $c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish this you have to use concept of global variable

Try this:

```
$list_a = array(); //defining an array
 $list_b = array();
 $list_c = array();
function addText($a,$b,$c)
{
 global $list_a, $list_b, $list_c;
 array_push($list_a,$a);
 array_push($list_b,$b);
 array_push($list_c,$c);
}
addText('12','23',12);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($list_a);
print_r($list_b);
print_r($list_c);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work but it is bad design. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715897/why-is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-global-reference-inside-functions) why.

```
<?php

$list_a = array(); //defining an array
$list_b = array();
$list_c = array();
function addText($a,$b,$c)
{
    global $list_a, $list_b, $list_c;

    $list_a[] = $a;
    $list_b[] = $b;
    $list_c[] = $c;
}
function foreachThem()
{
    global $list_a, $list_b, $list_c;

    foreach($list_a as $item)
    {
         //...
    }
    foreach($list_b as $item)
    {
         //...
    }
    foreach($list_c as $item)
    {
         //...
    }
}
```

A better way would be saving them in a parent array (this is optional but it reduces the amount of parameters and therefor the amount of code) and passing it as reference. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) for info on passing by reference.

```
<?php

$theLists = array(
    "a" => array(),
    "b" => array(),
    "c" => array()
);
               // note the '&'
function addText(&$lists, $a,$b,$c)
{
    $lists["a"][] = $a;
    $lists["b"][] = $b;
    $lists["c"][] = $c;
}
                   // '&' is not needed here
function foreachThem($lists)
{
    foreach($lists["a"] as $item)
    {
         //...
    }
    foreach($lists["b"] as $item)
    {
         //...
    }
    foreach($lists["c"] as $item)
    {
         //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php

 $list_a = array(); //defining an array
 $list_b = array();
 $list_c = array();
addText($a,$b,$c)
{
   $list_a[] = $a;
   $list_b[] = $b;
   $list_c[] = $c;
}
public function 'function_name'($list_a, $list_b, $list_c) {
  foreach ($list_a as $list) {
    echo $list;
  }
}
```